# Inodes numbers keep changing

Tags: inode

As shown below, after deleting duplicated files, the number of inodes keeps changing. I do not understand why this is happening. The file system is xfs. Can you guys give some tips?

```
my-linux:/content# df -i .
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/md3             46295616 43991622 2303994   96% /content

my-linux:/content# df -i .
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/md3             114738816 43959820 70778996   39% /content

my-linux:/content# df -i .
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/md3             94207328 43960396 50246932   47% /content
```

Comment: Formatting improvements.

Comment: Probably needs to be on Server Fault or Super User, since this is very strange behavior.